# This pointer and suqare bracket overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

I have a problem when accessing the overflowed square bracket in a public method of my class. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
template<unsigned int DIM> class Vector
{
private:
    double mData[DIM];
public:
    Vector(double tableau[DIM])
    {
        for(int i=0; i<DIM; i++)
        {
            mData[i] = tableau[i];
        }
    }
    double operator[](int index)
    {
        assert(index < DIM);
        assert(index > -1);
        assert(-pow(10,-6)<=mData[index]<=1+pow(10,-6));
        if(mData[index]>=0 && mData[index]<=1)
        {
            return mData[index];
        }
        else if(mData[index]<0 && mData[index]>=pow(10,-6))
        {
            return 0.0;
        }
        else if(mData[index]>1 && mData[index]<= 1+ pow(10,-6))
        {
            return 1.0;
        }
    }
    double getDim() const
    {
        return DIM;
    }
    void print() const
    {
        for(int i=0;i<getDim();i++)
        {
            cout << this[i] << " "; //PROBLEM!!
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    double err=pow(10,-6);
    double tableau[5];
    tableau[0] = 0.5;
    tableau[1] = 0.79;
    tableau[2] = err;
    tableau[3] = 1+err;
    tableau[4] = 0;
    Vector<5> proba(tableau);
    proba.print();
}
```

I have tried with *this, this->, but anything appeared to work.
I hope you could help me.
Florent

Comment: `this->operator[](i)`

Comment: This line is also wrong:
assert(-pow(10,-6)<=mData[index]<=1+pow(10,-6));

It will compile but not work how you expect

Answer (score 1):

Member operator overloads require a value or reference of the class type, and `this` is a pointer.  So you either need to dereference the `this` pointer prior to using the operator, like this:

```
(*this)[i]
```

Or you can call the operator directly, which has the advantage of being totally explicit in its intent, but has the disadvantage of being a bit wordy and a bit more obscure (and therefore more likely to trip up anyone who reads it):

```
this->operator[](i)
```

---

If you have already tried `*this[i]` and found that it doesn't fix the problem, that's because it actually means `*(this[i])`!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from wrong implementation of operator[], there is wrong use of it:-

```
cout << this[i] << " ";
```

This should be

```
 cout << (*this)[i] << " "; //is you want to implement that way...
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is just a pointer, so to access `operator[]` you can either dereference it first:

```
cout << (*this)[i] << " ";
```

Or call the function directly (not preferred):

```
cout << this->operator[](i) << " ";
```